# Python: Recursion Limit Reached while Importing

Tags: python

When ever I am trying to import a file named "tttnums.py" I always get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Marcsegal/Dropbox/Programs/ttt finished.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tttnums
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded during compilation
```

This is the contents of tttnums.py:

```
tttSets = [
[7, 1, 4, 0, 3, 2, 8, 6, 5, 'L']
[0, 6, 5, 4, 2, 8, 1, 3, 7, 'W']
[2, 8, 0, 5, 6, 7, 4, 3, 1, 'W']
(continued with 40317 more lists)
]
```

I assume the reason I got this error is because I have so many lists in the file (40320 to be exact). How do I fix this error?

Comment: Are the inner lists in tttSets not missing a comma at the end?

Comment: I don't think a recursion limit should happen from reading a list. There are no other imports in tttnums.py?

Comment: Add the missing commas at the end of the inner lists and you won't see the error any more.

Comment: Ooh nice catch @MarkDickinson

Answer (score 2):

If the whole content of `tttnums.py` is just that data structure, it makes much more sense to store it in a plain text or .`json` file and just read it than to import it as a `.py` file.